# How can I request a permission to Manage External Storage with Unity's JavaCLass in C#

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-permissions

I want to create music related android game in unity. And I want that user can choose game music from his device if he want to.I could manage to do that in android 10 and below with unity's permssion requests'. But in unity i cant request a permission to manage external storage for android 11 and upper api level's. I tried to do that with AndroidJavaClass in Unity but at the end I couldn't manage to do that because i couldn't get AndroidJavaClass and AndroidJavaObject that well. I wrote this code at the below but it throw's an exeption that ***UnityEngine.AndroidJavaExeptoin: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCES_PERMSSION***

```
try
{
    //AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaClass context = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Context");
    AndroidJavaClass settings = new AndroidJavaClass("android.provider.Settings");
    AndroidJavaObject intent = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent",settings.Call<String>("ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION"),"package:"+Application.identifier);
    context.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("startActivity", intent);
    StartCoroutine(MySecondRoutine());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    myConsole.text += e + "\n";
    throw;
}
```

I also have tried it with `settings.Get<String>` but result was the same. So please help me request that permssion in Unity

Answer (score 0):

```
using var buildVersion = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Build$VERSION");
using var buildCodes = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Build$VERSION_CODES");

//Check SDK version > 29
if (buildVersion.GetStatic<int>("SDK_INT") > buildCodes.GetStatic<int>("Q"))
{
    using var environment = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Environment");
    //сhecking if permission already exists
    if (!environment.CallStatic<bool>("isExternalStorageManager"))
    {
        using var settings = new AndroidJavaClass("android.provider.Settings");
        using var uri = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
        using var unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        using var currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        using var parsedUri = uri.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", $"package:{Application.identifier}");
        using var intent = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent",
            settings.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION"),
            parsedUri);
        currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).